# How to convert selected datetime picker value to timespan in Blazor

Tags: time, blazor, datetimepicker, blazor-server-side, timespan

When reading from the database it's getting a value. But when I tried to add a new time slot as time (want to convert this to timespan as the database field is declared as `Time(7)` so the format is `hh:mm:ss:fffffff`) I found it difficult to save that.

I tried `datetimepicker`, then I tried `time` also, but its getting error.

#### My model class:

```cs
public class Model
{
  public short TimeSlotID { get; set; }
  public TimeSpan FromTime { get; set; }
  public TimeSpan ToTime { get; set; }
}
```

#### Timerazor.razor

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div id="datetimepicker-control">
       <!--<input type="time" name="FromTime" value="@item.FromTime.ToString("hh mm tt")" /> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
       <input type="time" name="FromTime" value="@item.ToTime.ToString("hh mm tt")" />
    </div>
@code
{
   // i dont know how to pass the timespan value while inserting the time. here.
    int rows = timeslotdal.InsertTimeSlot(modeltimeSlot);
}
```

#### for inserting

```cs
public int Insert(Model model)
{
   List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
   {
      new SqlParameter("@TimeSlotID",  model.TimeSlotID),
      new SqlParameter("@FromTime", model.FromTime),
      new SqlParameter("@ToTime",  model.ToTime),
   };

   return db.ExecuteNonQuery("storedproceduremodel", parameters);}
}
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear (I am guessing English is not your primary language), so I will _attempt_ to edit it so people can help. Please correct my edit if I have misunderstood. Also you mention `datetimepicker` but don't clearly explain what this is - there is no such HTML input type so you might want to add this.

Comment: Does this similar question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868854/how-to-bind-input-of-type-time-with-blazor

Comment: thank you for look into my question. Actually my requirement is adding and editing the timespan value to the database through razor page in Blazor. so in database the column Fromtime iis declared as Time(7),thats y i used Timespan in Blazor.  i dont know how could i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a `<input type='time'>` control to a  C# `TimeSpan` directly, you will need to add an intermediate step of binding to a `DateTime` and then pass the time element of the value through to the `TimeSpan` property.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869699/41403 for an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime? value = DateTime.Now;
if (value.HasValue)
{
    TimeSpan timeOnly = value.Value.TimeOfDay;
    // Assign the timeOnly value to your WorkStartTime property
    // assuming it's within a class or object
    WorkStartTime = timeOnly;
}
```